# Using OmniFaces 2.1 ViewScoped with Spring 3.1.0 in JSF 2.2

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, jboss-weld

I'm trying to convert some pages to View scope (from Session Scope) to enable multiple browser tabs to support showing data from multiple entries from a datatable.

Does anyone know whether following the steps in this PrimeFaces blog [Porting JSF 2.0′s ViewScope to Spring 3.0](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=702) will work to extend Spring to use `org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped` from Omnifaces 2.1?

Comment: How exactly is the given porting example insufficient for you that you're specifically asking to use OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`?

Comment: I just read today, somewhere I cannot now find, that from JSF 2.2 you should use the JSF ViewScope, not the Omnifaces one.

Comment: @EJP: In JSF 2.0/2.1 the `@PreDestroy` or `@ViewScoped` beans wasn't always properly taken into account. OmniFaces fixed that. Later in JSF 2.2, it was fixed too. So using OmniFaces `@ViewScoped` has no benefit in JSF 2.2. However, it isn't clear to me if that Spring port also takes destroy into account or not. Perhaps it failed to properly trigger/perform destroy and therefore OP was asking specifically for OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for your response. It was more a question to determine if this has been done before and whether there were any issues as such, but I haven't noticed any limitations as you have described as a possibility. If there are no known differences between using JSF 2.2 or omnifaces in Spring I'll try the standard JSF 2.2 one. I'm happy to accept your comment above describing no benefit etc as an answer to my question. Feel free to cut and paste and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the approach described in the blog you found. Only you don't and can't exactly port in such way that it under the covers actually uses the specific `@ViewScoped` annotation. Basically, you should implement the same code as those annotations are under the covers using.

Both the standard JSF `@ViewScoped` and the OmniFaces `@ViewScoped` do under the covers basically the same as descibed in the blog: referencing the bean instances via [`UIViewRoot#getViewMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewMap--). Only, the JSF 2.0/2.1 `@ViewScoped` didn't properly trigger `@PreDestroy` of beans in all cases. E.g. they won't be called when the underlying HTTP session expires. OmniFaces had solved those issues for JSF 2.0/2.1 users. JSF itself has solved them in 2.2. So in JSF 2.2 there is not really a reason to use OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`.

<sup>Although I'd like to hint here that I'm for future OmniFaces 2.2 planning to add a `beforeunload` hook to `<o:form>` when an OmniFaces `@ViewScoped` bean is used, so that the bean also really get destroyed when the user navigates away by GET, or refreshes the page, or closes the browser window, making it yet more useful again :)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your response. I noticed this link: https://github.com/javaplugs/spring-jsf does this link suggest that proper bean destruction is being performed?

Comment: I don't dare to say as I'm not into Spring.

Comment: Quick update: using the example link above it certainly works. Although it is not entirely clear to me whether I need to do anything in the registerDestructionCallback method or not, or whether it would be handled automatically.  This is what I currently have (it's empty, but does indeed get called): Override
 public void registerDestructionCallback(String arg0, Runnable arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  log.debug("registerDestructionCallback for bean " + arg0);
 }